# need help (or literature) with an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

> Hello, during my master thesis i came across an optimization problem
>   which essentially has the form:
>   $\min_{(n,L) \in \mathbb{N}^2} n C_1 h^{-rL}$
>   such that $C_2h^{q_1 L}+\frac{C_3}{n^{1-\frac{1}{p}}}h^{q_3L} \leq \epsilon$

for given parameters $C_i,q_i,h,p,r$ and $\epsilon$.
I have never seen such a problem and I'm curious if there are theorems or literature you can recommend.

Comment: Well, generally it is a nonlinear integer program, but as you only have two variables over the non-negative integers, a simple brute-force enumeration is likely going to be the fastest way to solve the problem

Comment: thanks now i got some keywords to google. Would that approach still work if the $C_i,q_i,h,pr,\epsilon$ are unknown/arbitrary? and can you recommend some literature?

Comment: If you want to optimize over more than two variables, enumeration would probably no longer be the best approach. I don't have any direct reference, just search for mixed-integer nonlinear programming and you will find loads of material. FYI, it is generally a very (very!) hard problem.